# Material not working using express routing

Tags: express, angular-material, angular-cli, express-router

> I am using angular/material in my angular-cli application it works
>   fine but i have implemented 2 bootstrap theme for each panels (front
>   end and client portals) when i use client portal saperately material
>   works fine but when i redirect from front end theme to my client
>   portal using express routing my angular material not working
>   pagination works properly but my mat-select is not showing dropdown
>   and view of angular material is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I problem was it not getting my modules css file because i am rendering from another cli application to make it working i have updated on my main angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
  ],
```

to my particular app styles array and it works fine.